# How to keep track of the index in an array

Tags: c++, arrays

I need to create a stats sheet that records the amount of touchdowns performed by a certain team. I have it working for the first round when it records all 8 teams, however in the semifinals since only 4 teams make it, it does not keep track of what index the winning teams were on and just couts the stats in a regular order from 0 - 4. Ive been thinking for a couple days now on how I could possibly overcome this but I havent been able to find a solution yet.

the stats table that is outputted

Please let me know if i can contribute anymore information to make my question less vague and easier for you to understand. I appreciate all the help, thank you.

Comment: If you don't care about the losers, then remove them from the list of current players.  Use a container for this such as vector, list, map, heck, any STL container.

Comment: i forgot to mention this but we arent allowed to use vectors